# Is it possible to draw a letter "T" on every rational number such that they do not intersect?

Tags: real-analysis

The upper part of the letter "T"-s are closed and bounded non degenerate intervals, and the perpendicular part (which is also bounded, closed, non degenerate) must be inside the upper part (cannot be at the edges).

I have proved that there are at most countable disjoint "T"-s in the plane. Also, if the perpendicular part of the T could be at the edges, then it is possible to erect such T-s. (The height of the T's follow a strictly monotone decreasing function, and the perp. part is at the left edge, then the width of the upper part can be arbitrary).

Any hints, ideas or solutions are welcome! I have been going crazy over this.

Comment: Ford circles  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted at by Will's comment, we can easily place the "T"'s inside of Ford circles. The wiki on [Ford Circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle) gives that the Ford circle at $p/q$ denoted $C[p/q]$ is disjoint or tangent to every other Ford circle. So if we just make the height of the "T" at $p/q$, lets say $T[p/q]$, the same as the radius of the Ford Circle, $(1/2q^2)$ and the length of the top part of the "T", half this radius, $(1/4q^2)$, then they will not touch one another. In the end, we can define the set $$T[p/q]= \{(p/q,y): 0\leq y\leq (1/2q^2) \}\cup \{(x,(1/2q^2)): (p/q-1/8q^2)\leq x\leq (p/q+1/8q^2) \}$$
as described. It should be noted that $p/q$ is the reduced fraction of the rational number, and we can take $0=0/1$